# prove the inequality using inequalities like AM GM HM OR CAUCHY or WEIRSTRASS ETC.

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

The inequality to be proven is 
$$ 2^n \gt 1 + n\cdot \sqrt{2^{n-1}} for\ all\ n>2 $$
using any inequalities like am gm hm cauchy schwarz tchebychev etc
I recently studied inequalities came across this question please help

Comment: Does this look like a tight inequality for large $n$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Your post is going to attract downvotes with the upper case sentences. A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Write $2^n-1$ as a sum of powers of two.

Comment: Is n an integer?

Comment: i don't know what n is as it is not given in the question i think n is a real number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If n $\epsilon \mathbb{N}$, apply AM-GM on $1, 2, 2^{2}......., 2^{n-1}$. $$\frac{1 + 2 + 2^{2} +......+2^{n-1}}{n}  \geqslant \sqrt[n][1*2*....*2^{n-1}]$$
$$\implies \frac{2^{n} - 1}{n} \geqslant \sqrt[n][2^{n*(n-1)/2}]$$
$$\implies \frac{2^{n} - 1}{n} \geqslant \sqrt[2][2^{n-1}]$$
$$\implies 2^{n} \geqslant 1 + n*\sqrt[2][2^{n-1}]$$
Equality holds at n=1.

Comment: thank you so much Prakhar Neema